# Definition of Natural Sort (edge cases)

Tags: sorting, natural-sort

A "natural sort" differs from a well-defined lexicographic sort; it attempts to match human expectation, for example sorting "10 cats" after "2 cats", not before.

However, in implementing a natural sort, there are many edge cases I'm not sure of. For example, in each of the following sets, consider which sorts first:

- Leading zero: `0 cats`, `00 cats`, `01 cat`, `1 cat`
- Whitespace: `0 cats`, `0  cats`
- Whitespace:  `a cat`, `a cat`
- Accents: `éclairs`, `eclairs`
- Casing: `a cat`, `A cat`
- Casing/Cascade: `a1`, `A0`, `a0`, `A1`
- Casing/Truncation: `a`, `A cat`, `A`, `a cat`
- Truncation: `cat`, `catalog`
- Separators: `a cat`, `a,cat`
- Separators/Decimals: `1 animals`, `1.1 cats`, `1.13 dogs`, `1.2 iguanas`
- …

My question is NOT your personal opinion on each of the above. My question is:

Do there exist any precise definitions of "Natural Sort" that clarify edge cases above?

---

*I recognize that there is no single authority that can make a single definition that everyone has to abide by. I recognize that some applications of a natural sort may want to sort `1`, `1.11`, `1.2` and others may want to sort `1`, `1.2`, `1.11`. So, I'm not looking for **the** defintion. I'm looking for any one (or more) reasonably-accepted,  precise definitions of how a natural sort should behave.*

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is *version sort*, which is simpler (and "almost standardised" ;-)

Comment: I ran into the same challenge when implementing [natsort](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) for Python. Ultimately I decided to allow the user to choose their desired algorithm for their use case precisely because there exists no formal definition.